# SQL Server Erro Ao converter o VarChar em Tipo Inteiro

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-select, sql-server-2012

SEGUE O ERRO

```
Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '280-64460-2' to data type int.
```

SQL FEITO

```
USE TOXICOLOGICO
SELECT NomeUnidadeColeta, NomeUnidadeColetaAlterar, Procedimento 
FROM dbo.Z_CADEIA_CUSTODIA_SHIFT 
WHERE Procedimento IN ('T01', 'T02', 'T03', 'T05', 'T07', 'T08', 'T12P', 'T03P')
AND NomeUnidadeColeta IN ('Marilia Toxicológico', 'Marilia Toxicológico CLT', 'Marilia Concurso Toxicológico CLT')
```

Comment: Poderia incluir o formato da tabela `Z_CADEIA_CUSTODIA_SHIFT`?

Comment: @HugoGuedes: A mensagem de erro relata uma tentativa de converter uma expressão string para valor numérico. No código que transcreveu não há conversão visível. //  Z_CADEIA_CUSTODIA_SHIFT é tabela, exibição ou o quê?

Comment: Esse erro deve ser de outra query, não? Afinal fala que vc esta tentando converter